# Which constructor is called in the following code

Tags: java, memory, constructor

I am confused as to the purpose of empty constructors, let me ellaborate:

if I have a class..

```
public class Test {
  private int x;
  private int a[];
  private static int y;

  public Test() {
     a = new int[3];
  }
}
```

I know that there exists an empty default constructor:

```
public Test() {
                      //or at least I think it exists
}                     //what is its purpose?
```

if I have a main method and code the following:

```
Test t1 = new Test();
```

Which constructor is called? or is the empty constructor overwritten by the one which instantiates a[]?

If I then instantiate 5 instances of Test, how many integer memory locations are allocated?

Sooo confused....

Comment: This looks like you are doing homework.  I would read over the rules of posts a question.  Also make sure you do research and search the web yourself as well in order to avoid a reaction like this.

Comment: You are right, by default there will be a default constructor i.e. one with no parameters.  if you write your own constructor that also takes no parameters, then this will override the default constructor.

Comment: The empty constructor only exists if you don't define one explicitly.

Comment: To clarify: The default constructor is *only* created by the compiler if you don't have *any* constructors. Any constructor, even one with parameters, will suppress the default constructor.

Comment: Thank you for that @Scary Wombat, shmosel and Andreas, that clarifies that bit for me. I didn't realize the default was being suppressed by the no-parameter method.

Thanks for nothing Dale.

Answer (score 0):

The empty constructor is inherited from the Object class, which is the superclass of all classes in Java. It merely allocates memory of the objects, but does not initialize anything.
So for every object it is possible to call `new A()`, even if `public A()` is not defined explicitly.
Sometimes you don't need to do extra job in the constructor, so you can just use the default one without bothering reimplementing it.

When a child class overwrites it, then the one called is the new one. It makes perfect sense, because when you bother overwriting a method, you want to be able to use it instead of the default one.

In your examples, the `Test` class contains 2 integers, and an array of 3 integers.
Each time you instantiate a new `Test`, you allocate space for two more integers and the array of three integers. This is why those are called *instance* variables: it means they belong to an instance. So each instance has its own.

Comment: Claverine so you're saying that even though I'm calling the constructor and it initializes the array of three (variable a), the system still allocates memory for the other two int x and static int y?

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked the static int y. A static attribute is a class variable, that is it is the same for all instances. So when calling the constructor, space is allocated for x and a. Space for y is allocated in the class only once, no matter how much instances you create. So yes, when you instantiate 5 instances, the system allocates 4 integers for each instance (for x and a) plus 1 integer for y (shared by all instances). That is a total of 21 integers.

Comment: Thank you for that!

@T.Claverine and this is so even though the constructor makes no mention of int x (only 'a' is initialized)... what is being held in each instance's x value; is it null?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not define any constructor for your class then compiler will automatically add a default parameter-less constructor to your class definition so that objects can be created using new keyword. If you explicitly define a parameter-less constructor (the way you have done) yourself then compiler will not add anything from his side.

So in this line of code

```
Test t1 = new Test();
```

the constructor that you have defined explicitly will be called.

To answer your second question - Each instantiation of your class results in allocation of memory required to hold an array containing 3 integers. For 5 instances it will simply become 5 times.

i.e. `5 * 3 * memory occupied by one integer`

Answer (score 0):

> Which constructor is called? or is the empty constructor overwritten by the one which instantiates a[]?

Since you have provided constructor for Test class, your constructor will be called. ***If you want to call super class constructor explicitly***, change your code as

```
 public Test() {
     super();
      a = new int[3];
 }
```

From oracle documentation page on [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor

---

> If I then instantiate 5 instances of Test, how many integer memory locations are allocated?

1. JVM will allocate space for 1 integer  for static variable ( int y, which is class or static variable)
2. JVM will allocate space for 1 integer for each Test instance for int x, which is instance variable
3. JVM will allocate space for 3 integers for each Test instance for int a[] array, which is instance variable

Total : Space for 5 + 5 + 15 (=25) integers